# Looking for a more efficient way to pull data from multiple datasets in SAS

Tags: performance, sas, pull

I'm trying to find a more efficient and speedier way (if possible) to pull subsets of observations that meet certain criteria from multiple hospital claims datasets in SAS. A simplified but common type of data pull would look like this:

```
data out.qualifying_patients;
set in.state1_2017
    in.state1_2018
    in.state1_2019
    in.state1_2020
    in.state2_2017
    in.state2_2018
    in.state2_2019
    in.state2_2020;

array prcode{*} I10_PR1-I10_PR25;

do i=1 to 25;
    if prcode{i} in ("0DTJ0ZZ","0DTJ4ZZ") then cohort=1;
end;

if cohort=1 then output;
run;
```

Now imagine that instead of 2 states and 4 years we have 18 states and 9 years -- each about 1GB in size. The code above works fine but it takes FOREVER to run on our non-optimized server setup. So I'm looking for alternate methods to perform the same task but hopefully at a faster clip.

I've tried including (KEEP=) or (DROP=) statements for each dataset included the SET statement to limit the variables being scanned, but this really didn't have much of an impact on speed -- and, for non-coding-related reasons, we pretty much need to pull all the variables.

I've also experimented a bit with hash tables but it's too much to store in memory so that didn't seem to solve the issue. This also isn't a MERGE issue which seems to be what hash tables excel at.

Any thoughts on other approaches that might help? Every data pull we do contains customized criteria for a given project, but we do these pulls a lot and it seems really inefficient to constantly be processing thru the same datasets over and over but not benefitting from that. Thanks for any help!

Comment: This it probably too big of a topic for SO.  Why not check out whether "Odyssey"  https://www.ohdsi.org/ has any methods of analysis that could help.

Comment: Are these datasets SAS data sets or are they on a sql server somewhere? I suspect you're getting data from a server and a large part of the time is downloading the data, and possibly filtering on the SAS side, not the server side.

Comment: @Tom Thank you -- was not familiar with this site. Will definitely check it out.

Comment: @Reeza The datasets are all in SAS format. They are stored on a shared drive but not an optimized or high-powered server (which may be the root of the issue -- but I wanted to make sure there were no coding methods I was overlooking).

Answer (score 1):

I happend to have a 1GB dataset on my compute, I tried several times, it takes SAS no more than 25 seconds to set the dataset 8 times. I think the `set` statement is too simple and basic to improve its efficient.
I think the issue may located at the do loop. Your program runs do loop 25 times for each record, may assigns to `cohort` more than once, which is not necessary. You can change it like:

```
do i=1 to 25 until(cohort=1);
  if prcode{i} in ("0DTJ0ZZ","0DTJ4ZZ") then cohort=1;
end;
```

This can save a lot of do loops.

Comment: Thank you for this! I'm not sure this will 100% resolve the broader speed issues but can only improve the speed -- much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

First, parallelization will help immensely here.  Instead of running 1 job, 1 dataset after the next; run one job per state, or one job per year, or whatever makes sense for your dataset size and CPU count. (You don't want more than 1 job per CPU.). If your server has 32 cores, then you can easily run all the jobs you need here - 1 per state, say - and then after that's done, combine the results together.

Look up [SAS MP Connect](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2021/01/13/running-sas-programs-in-parallel-using-sas-connect/) for one way to do multiprocessing, which basically uses rsubmits to submit code to your own machine.  You can also do this by using xcmd to literally launch SAS sessions - add a parameter to the SAS program of state, then run 18 of them, have them output their results to a known location with state name or number, and then have your program collect them.

---

Second, you can optimize the DO loop more - in addition to the suggestions above, you *may* be able to optimize using pointers.  SAS stores character array variables in memory in adjacent spots (assuming they all come from the same place) - see [From Obscurity to Utility:
ADDR, PEEK, POKE as DATA Step Programming Tools](https://www.lexjansen.com/nesug/nesug07/bb/bb15.pdf) from Paul Dorfman for more details here.  On page 10, he shows the method I describe here; you PEEKC to get the concatenated values and then use INDEXW to find the thing you want.

```
data want;
  set have;
  array prcode{*} $8 I10_PR1-I10_PR25; 
  found = (^^ indexw (peekc (addr(prcode[1]), 200 ), '0DTJ0ZZ')) or 
          (^^ indexw (peekc (addr(prcode[1]), 200 ), '0DTJ4ZZ'))
;
run;
```

Something like that should work.  It avoids the loop.

You also could, if you want to keep the loop, exit the loop once you run into an empty procedure code.  Usually these things don't go all 25, at least in my experience - they're left-filled, so I10_PR1 is always filled, and then some of them - say, 5 or 10 of them - are filled, then I10_PR11 and on are empty; and if you hit an empty one, you're all done for that round.  So not just leaving when you hit what you are looking for, but also leaving when you hit an empty, saves you a lot of processing time.

Comment: Very nice example of app functions! I know these functions but don't have much chance to use.

Comment: @Joe this is fantastic info -- I was not familiar with many of these methods. Will definitely give them a try and report back. Thank you! (and yes you are absolutely correct about the left-filled nature of the PR codes)

Answer (score 0):

You probably should consider a hardware upgrade or find someone who can tune your server. This [paper](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings17/1410-2017.pdf) suggests tips to improve the processing of large datasets.

Your code is pretty straightforward. The only suggestion is to kill the loop as soon as the criteria is met to avoid wasting unnecessary resources.

```
do i=1 to 25;
    if prcode{i} in ("0DTJ0ZZ","0DTJ4ZZ") then do;
        output;  * cohort criteria met so output the row;
        leave;   * exit the loop immediately;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks @floydn. Yes agreed -- part of why I put this question on SO was to see if server optimization was our only remaining solution or if there was something else we were missing that could work in the current environment. But your point is very well-taken and I will check out the link you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have resolved this or not, here is how I would go about it

```
    /* Create custom Informat to indicate flagged code values */
    proc format lib=work;
        invalue cohort
        '0DTJ0ZZ' = 1
        '0DTJ4ZZ' = 1
        other = 0
        ;
    run;

    /* Declare a macro to compose the final cohorts data set */
    %MACRO getCohorts(
      p_inLibname= /* SAS Libname containing your State level data sets */
    , p_stYear= /* Starting Years range */
    , p_endYear= /* Ending Years range */
    , p_colCount= /* Number of I10_PR columns to search through */
    , p_fmtName= /* Name of the custom informat */
    , p_outCohorDsName= /* Final cohorts output data set name */
    );
     
        %local l_cnt l_dsName;
        %let l_cnt=0;
    
        /* Reset the final cohorts record collection */
        %if (%sysfunc(exist(&p_outCohorDsName)) gt 0) %then
        %do;
            proc delete data=&p_outCohorDsName; run;
        %end;
        
        /* Get a complete list of all State level data sets */
        proc sql noprint;
            SELECT MEMNAME
            INTO :l_ds1 - :l_ds1000
            FROM dictionary.tables
            WHERE LIBNAME = UPCASE("&p_inLibname")
            AND MEMTYPE = 'DATA'
            AND (MEMNAME LIKE %unquote(%nrbquote('%%_%superq(p_stYear)'))
            %do y=%eval(&p_stYear+1) %to &p_endYear;
                 OR MEMNAME LIKE %unquote(%nrbquote('%%_%superq(y)'))
            %end;
            )
            ORDER BY MEMNAME;
        quit;
        %let l_cnt=&sqlobs;
        %put &=l_cnt;
        
        %if (&l_cnt GT 0) %then
        %do d=1 %to &l_cnt; 
            %let l_dsName = %superq(l_ds&d);
    
            /* Create a subset of the desired cohort records only */
            data state_sub(drop=i);
                if (0) then SET &l_dsName; 
                Array prcode {&p_colCount} I10_PR:;
                Array prcoden {&p_colCount} _temporary_;
    
                SET &l_dsName;
                do i=1 to &p_colCount;
                    prcoden[i]=input(prcode[i],&p_fmtName..);
                end;
                if (sum (of prcoden{*}) GE 1);
            run;
    
            /* Append to the final collection */
            proc append base=&p_outCohorDsName data=state_sub; run;
    
            /* Clean-up */
            proc delete data=state_sub; run;
        %end;
    %MEND getCohorts;
    /* for insight on what & how SAS processing */
    options mprint fullstimer msglevel=i;
    
    %getCohorts(p_inLibname=work,p_stYear=2017, p_endYear=2020, p_colCount=25, p_fmtName=cohort, p_outCohorDsName=work.final);
```

The above macro should be faster than using the SET statement against multiple data sets, because

1. Using Informat for the columns avoids the IF condition looping
2. Using Proc Append would use Block I/O to read multiple records from the subset at a time, while the SET statement would read single record at a time!

Hope this helps